# Indexing pdf and html files in solr shows error in html indexing

Tags: html, pdf, solr, lucene, solrcloud

Hi I am new in Solr and using Solr 7.0.0 running in windows 7. The Solr is running in cloud mode.
I created a collection and tried to index a list of pdf and html files residing in a folder using the following command:

```
> java -jar -Dc=guidanceDoc -Dauto example\exampledocs\post.jar M:\Projects\guidance\documents\*
```

The pdf files in my folder have no ".pdf" extension, however, the html files have htm extension.

While indexing using the above command, the pdf files are indexed without any error. However, during running the command, if the process gets an html file shows an error as follows:

```
> POSTing file ucm073837.htm (text/html) to [base]/extract
> SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for
> url: http
> ://localhost:8983/solr/guidanceDoc/update/extract?resource.name=M%3A%5CProjects%
> 5Cguidance%5Cdocuments%5Cucm073837.htm&literal.id=M%3A%5CProjects%5Cguidance%5Cd
> ocuments%5Cucm073837.htm SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {  
> "responseHeader":{
>     "status":400,
>     "QTime":10},   "error":{
>     "metadata":[
>       "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
>       "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
>     "msg":"Document contains multiple values for uniqueKey field: id=[M:\\Projec ts\\guidance\\documents\\ucm073837.htm, UCM073837]",
>     "code":400}} SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException : Server returned HTTP response code:
> 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/gu
> idanceDoc/update/extract?resource.name=M%3A%5CProjects%5Cguidance%5Cdocuments%5C
> ucm073837.htm&literal.id=M%3A%5CProjects%5Cguidance%5Cdocuments%5Cucm073837.htm
```

- How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of indexing this html files isn't related to extension. As it mentioned in the error message:

```
Document contains multiple values for uniqueKey field: id=[M:\\Projec ts\\guidance\\documents\\ucm073837.htm
```

Your uniqueKey shouldn't exists multiple times in the file. Another possibility is to change uniqueKey in the schema.xml to be some other field, but not an id field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The documents are pdf and html and I have not assigned any identifier by myself. Everything is done by solr automatically. Can you guide me more specifically?